# Making an HTML Link Open a New Electron Window

Tags: html, hyperlink, electron

I want to make an Electron app have different links, that open up other windows, but I am not sure exactly how to go about doing this.

From other questions here on Stack Overflow, it seems like the most common (or only) way is to do something like

```html
<a href="https://somewebsite.com" target="_blank">Open New Window</a>
```

But the initial window is created by something like:

```js
function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
}
```

Do we only create the initial window that way? Or can we do that for additional windows (from a link or something)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to enable `nativeWindowOpen` in your main window's `webPreference`'s to get a native Chrome window.

Then, clicking the link should automatically open in a new window. You should not need to create your own window manually.

That being said, you might want to intercept the window creation and change various properties about the window, which you can do via the [`setWindowOpenHandler`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssetwindowopenhandlerhandler)

Comment: Would this open a new window for every single link in a new window or only the ones that specify the target of "_blank"?

Comment: @JacobHornbeck you need to specify a target of _blank

Comment: Where do I put the `nativeWindowOpen` stuff... Is that in the `webPreferences` in the `createWindow()` function that I show in my initial question? Would it just be `nativeWindowOpen: true`?

Comment: @JacobHornbeck yes, correct on both points

Answer (score 0):

You can use  the shell command and open a external window. Here is code,

```html
<a href="https://somewebsite.com" target="_blank" onClick="open_link()">Open New Window</a>


open_link(event) {
    shell.openExternal(event.target.href);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does the `shell.openExternal(...)` do?

Comment: @JacobHornbeck It will open a window using the default browser I believe. The window won't be an Electron window

Comment: @JacobHornbeck Yeah correct there is another way like if you don't want to open a new window on each click then 

You can just create one window and make it hide. so when you click on the url just load the url and show up the window.